# where entre fechas guardadas mysql laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un where

```
->where('a.nombre', 'LIKE', '%'. $palabra . '%')
```

pero necesito crear otro en donde tengo dos campos fechas en la bd
("desde" , "hasta")estos son años y necesito verificar si un $valorx esta entre ese rango

Answer (score 1):

Usa un doble where (uno para cada campo de la base de datos), teniendo en cuenta que el valor debe ser mayor o igual que 'desde' y menor o igual que 'hasta':

```
where(function ($query) use ($valorx) {
    $query->where('desde', '>=', $valorx);
    $query->where('hasta', '<=', $valorx);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el dato que tienes es un año y en la BD tienes fechas, debes usar `whereYear` todo junto en el query builder de esta forma

```
->where('a.nombre', 'LIKE', '%'. $palabra . '%')
->whereYear('a.desde', '>=', $valorx)
->whereYear('a.hasta', '<=', $valorx);
```